# End request handler issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a web application which has update panel in its homepage.master. The end request handler has a jquery function for slider in it.

When page loads for the first time, the jquery for slider in fields.js is fired. But on partial postback on the same page, the endrequest handler jquery is executed.

Everything works fine in all browsers, except firefox.

Can anyone tell me, if firefox does not support end request handler?

The problem is that, in mozilla the slider gets loaded first time normally, but on any activity on the slider and then a button click (causing partial postback), the slider stops working.

Please provide me with solution for this.

Thanks